# href link to a view not working asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I have worked through several tutortials on Core 2 and razor but can't seem to get this very easy thing to work.
I drag/dropped a local view called Contact.cshtml to a razor About.cshtml file and it added the bottom line, it currently looks like this:

```
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About 1st Choice Web Portal";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>

<p>Internal Use Website only.</p>
<p>Currently Under Development.</p>
<p>For feedback please use our Contact page.</p>
<a href="~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml">~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml</a>
```

I just want it to show the Contact view when they click on the href.

There is a Contact.cshtml view under Views/Home.

The HomeController.cs has this:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "--- Under Development ---";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "For help and support please contact one of the below departments.";

        return View();
    }
```

When it runs it gets a:
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:65061/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this

```
<a asp-action="Contact" asp-controller="Home">Whatever</a>
```

instead of your

```
<a href="/> code
```

Comment: So simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link to a view. That's not how things work. You need an action that loads that view, and then you link to the route that directs to that action.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the .cshtml File directly, I would recommend letting routing do the work:

```
<a href="~/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
```

In MVC the .cshtml is typically not directly exposed.

Comment: This is basically the same thing I think...at least it gives me the same error message.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have removed /Views/ from the path. That said I think @T. Sardelis answer is the more MVC friendly one.

Answer (score -1):

You have to include @page before like this:

```
@page
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About 1st Choice 
Web Portal";
}
```

That will make your href be recognized